# How to create a Mobile Website

Tags: web, mobile

I'm working on a project for class. To create a website and a website for mobile users. The site is to recongize the type of device/browser accessing the page and send the appropiate form. So if I was to visit the site on IE8 it will direct me to the mainpage for IE8, if I was to access the site with a mobile device it will direct me to the mobile website main page automatically.

Also, I need to design the website for at least two different screen sizes.

I'm coding in HTML5, I do not know the type of server the site will be hosted on. The use of Javascript is extra credited. The project details are to "design a small mobile web site. The web site should be tested on one or more mobile devices. The iPod Touch device will be used as the base for testing."

I know how to do 8/10 of the requirements (except the two mentioned). I looked at W3C and didn't find anything.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do a Google for:

- CSS Browser Detection
- JavaScript Browser Detection

Also you should think twice about creating multiple sites - with basically the same content - or creating proper stylesheets that are referred from the same site.

Hope that get's you the other 2 requirements

NOTE: Since this is homework I won't post any links...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that ServerFault isn't the best place for this question...but aside from that, your question is a little vague.  A google search for "designing a mobile website" turns up what looks to be several pages of relevant information.  If you first try working with the information in those documents and then come back with specific questions (e.g., "I tried this and it behaved this way instead of the way I expected") you're apt to get better answers.